# Error saying my string is empty when defined on line right before Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The whole code looks fine to me, but I am a beginner, so please be patient if it is obvious.

My problem is that I get an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of object

`ehealth` is the enemy's health and this is for the assignment of a slime's stats

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyStats : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text Text;

    void Update()
    {
        string ehealth = GameObject.Find("VStorage").GetComponent<VStorage>().ehealth.ToString();

        Text.text = ehealth;
    }
}
```

I don't know what to try so I'm asking for you help. I tried changing some variable names but nothings changed

Comment: The error doesn't say that the string is empty, it says that one of the object references you are trying to access is`null` - this could be any of `Text` or `GameObject.Find`, etc

Comment: You declare `Text` but don't initialize it, so it's a good candidate. Get your debugger, put a breakpoint on thr line before where the exception was thrown (info, btw, you should have included with your question) and inspect all the variables as you step through. You're going to want to get familiar with using the debugger

Comment: Im not shure how to fix it beacuse the Text is defined and the Vstorage works on other scripts

Comment: No, `Text` is declared, but it's not initialized, so it has no value

Comment: How do i initialise it and how do i get a debugger. I know i might sound like an idiot

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to assign your "Text"-variable to a TMP in the inspector:[image: Drag the TextMeshPro (Text) in this slot]

Also most c#-programmers name variables with camelCase.